# Dúvidas sobre continuação nos estudos em C# e sugestões para conseguir um estágio

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, lógica

Olá,
Estou no 2° período do curso de SI, porém venho estudando C# por conta própria 
através da apostila da Caleum: C# e Orientação a Objetos. Estou gostando muito da linguagem 
e pretendo me aprofundar na plataforma para conseguir meu primeiro estágio e emprego.
A apostila é a seguinte e cobre estes assuntos: [C# e Orientação a Objetos](https://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-csharp-orientacao-objetos/)

Estou finalizando a apostila e para a fixação dos conceitos desenvolvi um projeto de um "Banco", passado pela apostila, e uma "agenda telefônica" utilizando os conceitos de OO e Coleções para testar meus conhecimentos.

Meu grande objetivo é conseguir pelo menos um estágio no início do ano que vem.Estaréi no 3° período da faculdade e tenho ai o resto desse ano para prosseguir nos estudos e realizar esse objetivo.

A minha dúvida é em relação ao prosseguimento nos estudos após ter concluído essa apostila da Caelum e quais os conhecimentos necessários para conseguir um estágio em uma empresa.

Banco de dados? ASP.NET MVC? Algum framework? Quais conhecimentos seriam indispensáveis e um diferencial?

Comment: Eu não gosto desta apostila, acho muito superficial, faz simplificações que causa mais dano que ajuda e coloca foco no que não é importante. Se ela é direcionada para principiantes direciona errado, se é para experientes, é boba. Posso garantir que se a pessoa só seguir a apostila vai achar que aprendeu OOP e na verdade não aprendeu. Note que se tivesse caminhando de forma apropriada nos seus estudos provavelmente saberia responder a pergunta feita. Quando se pula os fundamentos, passa ter que confiar em pessoas aleatórias para dizer o que é bom para você.

Comment: Diferencial hoje em dia é aprender desenvolver software de verdade. Quase ninguém faz isso, apenas decoram receitas de bolo, as pessoas acham que basta seguir as receitas de um *framework* e tudo se resolve, e não é assim, pelo menos para aprender mesmo.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Eu estudo por conta própria já que é um assunto bem a frente da faculdade e não dependo dela para aprender nada. Esse é o grande problema já que é a primeira linguagem de programação que estou aprendendo de forma séria, então com tantos materiais fica difícil saber onde começa uma coisa e termina a outra. Sobre a apostila, achei ela bem fácil de entender, porém com  você disse que é fraca, supondo que eu entenda o essencial da linguagem e os assuntos tratados nela. Quais são os passos seguintes que na sua opnião eu deveria dar para criar uma aplicação completa com DB?